# How to shutdown JMX programmatically?

Tags: java, jmx

We have an application server, which is started with, among other, these parameters:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345
```

So, we do not start JMX programmatically, but we would like to **close** it programmatically.

Just to be clear, *we are not looking to close our application using JMX*, but rather close JMX itself from the application.

The reason is, we have very many threads still running when the application closes, and we are trying to reduce that to the minimum, so we know why it sometimes "hangs" when closing. We do not think our application hangs because of JMX, but if it was shut down, along with *all the RMI threads it creates*, we would be 100% sure.